# Keyboard is hiding flutter_stripe CardFields, not pushing the screen

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-stripe

In my case, the CardField is positioned at the bottom of the screen. When the keyboard opens up on focus, it is not pushing to the screen to show the input fields. This happens only with the CardField, normal TextField is working fine. Here is the simplest code that is not working. Note that the stripe is working fine, no error there, I have to manually scroll up the input field.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //Mimic the other fields on the top of the card
            const SizedBox(
              height: 700,
            ),
            Row(
              children: const [
                //Stripe Input Fields
                Expanded(
                  child: CardField(
                    numberHintText: "Card Number",
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 30,
                ),

                //Basic TextField
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    autofocus: false,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[UI behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri78K.gif)

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days o searching, I was finally able to get a working workaround using a scroll controller ( mixed ideas from several SO answers):

```
class PlayGround extends StatelessWidget {
  PlayGround({super.key});

  //ScrollController
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        //Add adjustment if there are more elements after the CardField
        //This is just to try and see how much adjustment is needed
        double adjustment = 0.0;

        //Scroll up from the bottom
        _controller.animateTo(
          bottom + adjustment,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 30),
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
        );
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _controller,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: const [
            //Mimic the other fields on the top of the card
            SizedBox(
              height: 700,
            ),
            CardField(
              numberHintText: "Card Number",
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```